# Angular Promise trying Wrapper

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise

Sometimes I need to repeat an execution of rejected promises several times, for example, to fetch some data over internet.
There is a wrapper, which accepts Promise and tryCount:

```js
function tryPromise(f, tryCount) {
  return f().then(null, function(v) {
    tryCount--;
    if (tryCount > 0) {
      return $q.reject(v);
    }
    return tryPromise(f, tryCount);
  });
}
```

Is there some hidden troubles?

Comment: What is `$q` in `return $q.reject(v);`?

Comment: @Sergio Angular's Promise https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: if `tryCount` is `<= 0` that code will enter a loop and kill your browser if there is no waiting moment in `f`.. What numbers to you give `tryCount` when you invoque that function? will it ever be `<=0`?

Comment: @Sergio you are right, will be better to place additional conditional for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all you aren't trying a promise. What you're really doing is trying out a function that returns a promise. So the name is already misleading. Try something better.

Next, `f` and `v` doesn't really tell me anything. Only when I read through the code did I realize `f` was the function to try out and `v` is supposed to be a value. Additionally, even if you name `v` a value, it's still not correct. Most reject handlers often pass an error object.

Code that requires one to actually read to understand is a bad practice. In this case it's negligible due to the size of the function. But if you're in larger codebases, it's a nightmare to maintain. Name your functions and variables meaningfully.

Lastly, your function doesn't allow for function arguments. It would be nice to at least accept argument 3 onwards as the arguments, or accept an array that would be the arguments.

My take on it would be:

```
function tryPromiseFunction(functionToTry, retries, ...args){
  return functionToTry(...args).then(null, error => {
    return retries > 0 ? tryPromiseFunction(functionToTry, retries - 1, ...args)
                       : Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks good, many thanks. Not sure, should we compare `retries` with `> 1`instead `> 0` ?